# ¿Cómo limpar carácteres indeseables (SALTOS DE LINEA) en un texto? (Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token)

Tags: php, mysql, jquery, html5

Me ocurre un error que no logro resolver. Explico los pasos de todo lo que hice.

-Primero tenía un formulario en el cual había un "textarea"

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for=""><i>Descripción (600 carácteres máx.)</i></label> 
    <textarea class="form-control" name="Descripcion" id="descripcion" maxlength="600"  rows="5" required></textarea>
</div>
```

-Este campo fue relleno con texto y luego se guardó en una base de datos MySQL con cotejamiento UTF-8 (general) en phpMyAdmin.

-Seguidamente este texto se vuelve a leer desde la base de datos y se intenta poner nuevamente dentro del mismo "TextArea" usando JQuery y PHP.

```
$('#descripcion').text('<?php echo $datos_anuncio["DESCRIPCION"]; ?>')
```

Y obtengo este error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token
```

He estado revisando el texto y no veo caráteres extraños (solo acentos y eñes), no sé si habrá algún caracter extraño que no se visualice y me lo estoy pasando por alto.

¿Alguna forma de limpiar el texto de carácteres que puedan estar produciendo este error?¿O otra forma de resolver este problema sin tener que hacer la limpieza?

### ACTUALIZACIÓN

Acabo de averiguar que lo que estaba dando error era un salto de línea al final del texto (\r\n\r\n\r\n). El error se ha resuelto pero sigo con la misma duda. ¿Cómo limpiar el texto de este tipo de caracteres que causan errores?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para eliminar el (los) caracter de salto de línea de un `string` puedes usar el método `replace()`.

Lo siguiente debería funcionar:

```
var strSucio = 'Aqui va un texto de ejemplo con salto de linea al final \r\n';
var strLimpio = strSucio.replace(/[\r\n]+/g,  '');
```

Aqui hemos usado una expresión regular como parámetro de búsqueda de nuestro método `replace()`

`[\r\n]`: indica que buscaremos el salto de línea.

`+`: indica que puede haber más de un salto de línea.

`g`: indica que se hará una búsqueda global, es decir, que la búsqueda continuará aunque se haya conseguido ya una concordancia (match).

El segundo parámetro pasado a `replace()` es el caracter por el que vamos a reemplazar. En este caso, paso un caracter nulo.

**EDICIÓN**

Dado que el método `replace()` funciona con `string` válidos de Javascript, el problema que se presenta es que la variable PHP 'bindeada' no tiene el formáto válido de Javascript.

La solución está en limpiar la variable antes de pasarla a Javascript. Esto lo logramos usando la función `preg_replace()` de PHP:

```
$('#descripcion').text( '<?php echo preg_replace('/[\r\n]+/',  '', $datos_anuncio["DESCRIPCION"]); ?>')
```

En este caso, pasamos la expresión regular sin el modificador `g`, ya que el motor de PHP no lo acepta según la documentación de la [Sintáxis de Patrón PCRE](http://php.net/manual/es/reference.pcre.pattern.syntax.php).

Espero que esto te ayude a resolver tu problema.

Saludos

Comment: Hola @MauricioContreras!! Gracias por contestar!! No puedo hacer lo que dices porque el error me sale justo aquí (**var strSucio =  <?php echo $datos_anuncio["DESCRIPCION"]; ?>;**). Es decir, es la expresión en PHP la que está dando error y no asigna el valor a la variable de JavaScript. ¿Alguna otra idea?

Comment: Ya sé... voy a aplicar lo que dices antes de guardar en la base de datos a ver si funciona..

Comment: Aplícale el método a la variable PHP. Algo así: `var str= (<?php echo $datos_anuncio["DESCRIPCION"]; ?>).replace(/[\r\n]+/g,  '');` y me dices como va.

Comment: Tampoco se puede... lo voy a intentar con JavaScript tal y como dijiste al príncipio antes de guardar el texto en la base de datos y así al leerlo con PHP ya debería estar limpio. Te comento como me fue!!

Comment: Listo @IvánRodríguez, ya tienes completa la respuesta.

Comment: Hacerlo desde el princípio con JavaScript tal y como dijiste me funcionó perfecto!! También probé ha hacerlo con reg_remplace() pero sale esta advertencia (Warning: preg_replace(): Unknown modifier 'g' in).

Comment: Solo quítale el caracter `g` a la expresión regular y soluciinas ese error.

Comment: No se soluciona... vuelve al mismo error del princípio... pero bueno, al menos el método con JavaScript si que funciona a las mil maravillas.

Comment: Exvelente me alegra haberte ayudado.

Comment: Y yo!! :-)  Muchísimas Gracias @MauricioContreras!!