# ¿Cómo soluciono esto? (uncaugth typeerror cannot create property disabled on string)

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tengo un formulario que por ciertos errores que causaban los saltos de línea me vi obligado a poner un textarea oculto (hidden).

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for=""><i>Descripción (600 carácteres máx.)</i></label> 
    <textarea class="form-control" name="Descripcion" id="descripcion" maxlength="600"  rows="5" required></textarea>
    <textarea class="form-control" name="DescripcionLimpia" id="descripcion_limpia" maxlength="600"  rows="5" novalidate></textarea>

</div>
```

Esto ocasionó que al enviar los datos (submit) me lanzara otro error que decía que el textarea oculto no era **focusable.**

Encontré la siguiente función que me ayudó a solucionar ese problema:

```
$("body").on("submit", "#myForm", function(evt) 
{

    // Disable things that we don't want to validate.
    $(["input:hidden, textarea:hidden, select:hidden"]).attr("disabled", true);

    // If HTML5 Validation is available let it run. Otherwise prevent default.
    if (this.el.checkValidity && !this.el.checkValidity()) {
        // Re-enable things that we previously disabled.
        $(["input:hidden, textarea:hidden, select:hidden"]).attr("disabled", false);
        return true;
    }
    evt.preventDefault();

    // Re-enable things that we previously disabled.
    $(["input:hidden, textarea:hidden, select:hidden"]).attr("disabled", false);

    // Whatever other form processing stuff goes here.
});
```

Ahora todo funciona bien, pero después del submit aparece este otro error (he tenido que hacer una captura porque solo dura un segundo y luego desaparece).

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

A pesar de que todo funciona correctamente me sentiría mejor si este error no apareciera.

¿Alguna ídea de cómo solucionarlo?

Comment: Una pregunta. ¿Qué errores te causaban los saltos de línea? Porque tu solución al problema (input oculto) tal vez no es la más adecuada.

Comment: Hola!! El error era con PHP... no me dejaba volver a pasar el texto a JavaScript para volverlo a insertar en el textarea. https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/229359/c%c3%b3mo-limpar-car%c3%a1cteres-indeseables-saltos-de-linea-en-un-texto-uncaught-syn

Comment: Otra cosa, `disabled` no es un atributo, es una propiedad. La manera correcta de añadir o remover dicha propiedad es la siguiente: `$(["input:hidden, textarea:hidden, select:hidden"]).prop('disabled', true);`. Prueba eso y nos comentas. Saludos

Comment: Disculpa. Faltó poner el valor de la propiedad. Acabo de editar el comentario.

Comment: Ok, he cambiado "attr" por "prop" y sigue ocurriendo lo mismo.... El text area oculto era porque no podia usar el mismo para guardar el texto limpio (sin saltos de línea) y enviarlo al servidor. Si sabes una forma mejor para hacerlo yo estoy dispuesto a cambiar el código

Comment: Excelente. Puedes publicar tu respuesta. Saludos

Comment: ¿Excelente?... No, que vá!! Si no he solucionado nada!! Todo sigue igual... el error sigue apareciendo y no tengo ni idea de que hacer para que no aparezca!! .-(

Comment: Disculpa, leí mal. Volvamos al principio. Mi pregunta es porqué debes usar un `input` oculto? Mencionas que daba error con saltos de linea. Como te dije al principio, tal vez esa solución de poner `input` oculto no es la más idónea.

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/88339/discussion-between-mauricio-contreras-and-ivan-rodriguez).